# Dplyr: Recode numeric and character vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have a screen of death in my mind. How do I use `recode` in `dplyr`?

```
data = data.frame(id=rep(1:10, each=1), time=seq(1:5), char = strrep("a", 3))

library(dplyr) # everything throws an error
data %>% recode(time, `1` = 0)
data %>% recode(time, `1` = 0L)
data %>% recode(time, 1 = 0)
data %>% recode(time, 1 = 0L)

data %>% recode(char, aaa = 0)
data %>% recode(time, "aaa" = 0)
```

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `recode` takes a vector as argument, not a data.frame :

```r
data %>% mutate(time2 = recode(time, `1` = 0L))
data %>% mutate(char2 = recode(char, aaa = 0))
data %>% mutate(char2 = recode(as.character(char), aaa = 0))
```